# Access another user's custom profile property that has a custom type (class)

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile

I'm working with ASP.net and C#, trying to access another user's `Profile` Properties from the `web.config` file.

The property I want to access has a custom type of a class that I created, `ClassesList`:

```
public class ClassesList
{
    public struct Class_
    {
        public string name;
        public string teacherName;
        public string startDate, endDate;
        public int numOfEnrolledStudents;
        public int maxNumOfStudents;
        public string[] studentsNames;
        public string accessKey;
        public bool IsActive;
     }

     public Class_[] Classes;

     public ClassesList()
     {
        this.Classes = new Class_[200];

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Classes[i].IsActive = false;
            Classes[i].studentsNames = new string[500];
        }
     }
}
```

Here's my profile in the `web.config` file:

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="ClassList" type="ClassesList" allowAnonymous="false" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I'm using this statement to get the profile of another user (in a for loop)

```
ProfileBase currentTeacherProfile = ProfileBase.Create(teacherList[i], true);
```

So now I have the profile, I just need to access the profile property that I want, and that's `accessKey`

I'm trying to use this code to get the property, but I get the not found exception

```
currentTeacherProfile.GetPropertyValue("ClassList.Classes[0].accessKey")
```

NOTE: Accessing the current user's profile property using

```
Profile.ClassList.Classes[0].accessKey
```

works, but it doesn't work in the case of a different user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ProfileCommon otherProfile = Profile.getProfile("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the property value first (ClassesList)

```
ClassesList classList = currentTeacherProfile.GetPropertyValue("ClassList") as ClassesList;
```

Then, you can access that object's properties

```
classList.Classes[0].accessKey
```